# "the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite" error using 2l.norm in mice

Tags: r, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I am having a problem using the `2l.norm` method of multilevel imputation in `mice`.

Unfortunately I cannot post a reproducible example because of the size of my data - when I reduce the size, the problem vanishes.

For a particular variable, `mice` produces the following errors and warnings:

```
Error in chol.default(inv.sigma2[class] * X.SS[[class]] + inv.psi) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rgamma(n.class, n.g/2 + 1/(2 * theta), scale = 2 * theta/(ss *  :
  NAs produced
2: In rgamma(1, n.class/(2 * theta) + 1, scale = 2 * theta * H/n.class) :
  NAs produced
3: In rgamma(1, n.class/2 - 1, scale = 2/(n.class * (sigma2.0/H - log(sigma2.0) +  :
  NAs produced
```

If I use the `2l.pan`, `norm` or `pmm` methods, the problem does not occur.

The variable has the following distribution:
[image]

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   50.0   117.0   136.0   136.7   155.0   249.0    3124
```

Also, the class sizes have the following distribution:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   3.00   50.00   80.00   88.52  111.00  350.00
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have had a similar problem in MICE, see my self-discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539910/leading-minor-of-order-is-not-positive-definite-error-in-mice/20541500#20541500). The problem occurs because you have overfitted your model (too many parameters, variables), some variables are highly colinear or you have cases that have missings on all variables.

In my case the model was overfitted. One way to solve this issue is by adjusting the predictor matrix of MICE. You may give `imp$pred` where `imp`is your `mids` object, to look at the predictor matrix. You can use

`new.pred <- quickpred(data)`

`mice(..., pred=new.pred)`

to automatically generate a predictor matrix based on the bivariate correlations of the variables in the data (eg Pearson, Spearman), where .10 is the default cutoff. This may solve your problem. More generally build your models wisely and do not just include all variables you may have.