# "Error during wrapup: the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite" when trying to use LME with random slopes

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

This works fine:

```
lme(fixed=target~target_projection, random= ~ 1|CLINICIAN_USER_ID, data=study_pop)
```

But if I try to let the slopes vary:

```
lme(fixed=target~target_projection, random= ~ target|CLINICIAN_USER_ID, data=study_pop)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error during wrapup: the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite
```

My data set should be large enough, the second level of the model breaks into 60 groups with 30 data points each, what could be causing this?

Comment: Searching our site for the key words in the error message, "leading minor," turns up the thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55925.  The information there might help you identify which additional details of your dataset you should share with us--and perhaps it even answers your question.

Comment: @whuber I did see that post, but it does not make sense for my issue. My data has no missing data points and there are only parameters, one of which is a factor, so it could not be colinear with the other.

Comment: You seem to be using "data" and "parameters" in an unconventional way.  In particular, what exactly do you mean by "only parameters"?  Please note, too, that the answer in the linked thread points to other potential causes of this problem, including overfitting, which is a possibility you should consider.

Comment: Sorry, a symbol got left out, I meant to say there are only 2 parameters. I know from manual plotting of the data that it could not be overfit with what I have provided to lme.

Comment: What package is this from?

Comment: Shouldn't `random= ~ target|CLINICIAN_USER_ID` be `random= ~ target_projection|CLINICIAN_USER_ID`? I can coax a similar error out of the `Oats` data using `m2 <- lme(yield~nitro,random = ~yield|Block,data=Oats)`

Comment: You can start to rule out a programming/data issue by running `traceback()` after the error

Comment: @alexforrence You are correct, I had made a syntax mistake. If you repeat that as an answer I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a syntax error; the random effect `random= ~ target|CLINICIAN_USER_ID` should be specified as `random= ~ target_projection|CLINICIAN_USER_ID`.

It's possible to (sort of) reproduce this using the `Oats` dataset:

```
library(nlme)

m1 <- lme(yield ~ nitro, random ~ 1|Block, data = Oats) #fine

m2 <- lme(yield ~ nitro, random = ~yield|Block, data=Oats)
##Error in chol.default((value + t(value))/2) : 
##the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite
```